# Linux tool to create a full backup of a SSD

Tags: linux, usb, backup, ssd

I want to do backups from SSD's and HDD's, which are connected via a USB converter to my workstation. The backups should be bootable (after restoring of course^^), the tool shouldn't need configuration besides the parameters given via terminal and the backup should be just one file to make storing and version control easier.

The scripts I found up until now quite didn't met my requirements. rsnapshot needs a whole conf-file and doesn't seem to support usb-mounted drives, dd afaik isn't bootable, same for cp, which also outputs more than one file (well, it could output one but that one won't be restorable).

Sadly I can't find more about this - does anybody have suggestions for such programs or can tell me if I'm wrong with one of the programs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want a backup that you can restore and boot up from straight away ?

Comment: Do you mean the `dd` linux/unix command isn't bootable? If so, what do you mean `dd` isn't bootable? `dd` just does a 'disk dump', so if the disk you `dd` from is bootable, then the disk you `dd` to will be bootable as well...and if you want an 'image' of the disk you could do 'something' like the following `dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /mnt/sda1/hda.img.gz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `dd` command, but make sure that your input file is the entire disk, not just one partition. Also, as Jonas pointed out, **you must first unmount any filesystems that reside on the disk to be copied** to prevent data corruption.

Use something like: `dd if=/dev/sda of=backupfile`

Instead of this: `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=backupfile`

This will ensure that you include the partition table and master boot record, boot sectors, etc.

The resultant file will contain a full image of the disk that, when restored onto the same (or similar) disk, will be fully bootable as before. Notice the caveat about a similar disk: obviously the target disk needs to contain at least the same number of sectors, otherwise you will potentially lose data; as for a larger target disk, I don't think there would be an issue - except for the waste of space.

You will probably need to run the `dd` command as root or via `sudo` since you will be accessing the raw device file.

I've used this technique many times with great success. You will also have the ability to directly mount the file as a virtual disk using a loop device or converting it for use in a virtual machine under VirtualBox, for example.

Comment: One must make sure not to access the drive during that though (for example, by having the file system mounted), otherwise the backup might be inconsistent (read: damaged).

Comment: @jonas Yes, good catch; that slipped my mind. +1

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that dd could do that - but I'm not a big SysTech.